# How can I automatically insert a datetime in this Angular6 Form?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the actual datetime filled in the new automatically made forms.

```
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      id: chatRoom.id,
      creationDate: chatRoom.creationDate != null ? chatRoom.creationDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT) : null,
      roomName: chatRoom.roomName,
      roomDescription: chatRoom.roomDescription,
      privateRoom: chatRoom.privateRoom,
      chatUserId: chatRoom.chatUserId
    });
```

Before I could use

```
      this.creationDate = moment().format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
      this.chatRoom.creationDate = moment(this.creationDate);
```

An explanation on how to do it, is also appreciated!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to create a const before using it like this:

```
    const date = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');

    this.editForm.patchValue({
      id: chatRoom.id,
      creationDate:
        proposal.creationDate != null
          ? proposal.creationDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
          : JSON.stringify(date)
              .split(':00.000Z')
              .join('')
              .split('"')
              .join(''),
      roomName: chatRoom.roomName,
      roomDescription: chatRoom.roomDescription,
      privateRoom: chatRoom.privateRoom,
      chatUserId: chatRoom.chatUserId
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could do something like this with `new Date()`.  Obviously if you need formatting, you could add that in.

```
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      id: chatRoom.id,
      creationDate: new Date(),
      roomName: chatRoom.roomName,
      roomDescription: chatRoom.roomDescription,
      privateRoom: chatRoom.privateRoom,
      chatUserId: chatRoom.chatUserId
    });
```

Comment: just noticed this notification, sorry for the delay.  Could you give me the error you get or any additional details so I can help you better?